# Does Remdesivir cause bone marrow suppression?

Tags: dna, rna, nucleotide

According to Wikipedia, [Remdesivir](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remdesivir) is a prodrug of [GS-441524](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GS-441524) which is a [nucleoside analog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nucleoside_analogue).

I know that nucleotides are the building blocks of both DNA and RNA, meaning nucleotide analogues that prevent the creation of viral RNA can also prevent the creation of normal cell DNA, meaning they can cause problems in dividing cells. This is also reflected in the nucleotide analogue article of Wikipedia:

> They are not specific to viral DNA and also affect mitochondrial DNA. Because of this, they have side effects such as bone marrow suppression.

So does Remdesivir cause bone marrow suppression?

If not please explain why.

Answer (score 1):

From [Off-Target In Vitro Profiling Demonstrates that Remdesivir Is a Highly Selective Antiviral Agent](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC7849018/):

> Overall, the cellular and biochemical assays demonstrated a low potential for RDV to elicit off-target toxicity, including mitochondria-specific toxicity, consistent with the reported clinical safety profile.

This isn't a very complete answer, but the wikipedia article doesn't go into detail or link references explaining the mechanism by which nucleoside analogues suppress bone marrow function. So I can't say if the assay results in my link rule out a suppression effect by remdesivir